# how to write this equation better way? the equation are quite long and it goes out of page

Tags: equations

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}



\begin{equation}

F^{(2)}_0(\chi, \Theta, \phi) &= \frac{1}{4}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)(3 \sin^2 \Theta \cos 2\chi-[3 \cos^2 \Theta -1])

\vspace{4 mm}

{\em F}^{(2)}_{1+}(\chi, \Theta, \phi) &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)c_2(j_i)(2 \sin \Theta \cos \phi \sin 2 \chi 
+ 2 \sin \Theta \cos \Theta \sin \phi \cos 2 \chi  - \sin 2 \Theta \cos \phi) 

\vspace{4 mm}

{\em F}^{(2)}_{2+}(\chi, \Theta, \phi) &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)c_2(j_i)([1 + \cos^2 \Theta] \cos 2\phi \cos 2\chi - 2 \cos \Theta \sin 2\phi \sin 2\chi {-}\sin^2\Theta \cos 2 \phi)\\

\vspace{2 mm}

\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Comment: if you get an error then fix the error don't look at the output. You can not have blank lines in equation, you can not use `&` and you can not use `\em`  or `\vspace` if you want people to help you should provide a small complete document with tthe example.

Comment: What is `{\em F}` supposed to stand for?

Answer (score 2):

The document produces

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11 

? 
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.11 

? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.12 F^{(2)}_0(\chi
                   , \Theta, \phi) &= \frac{1}{4}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)(3 \sin^2 \...

? 
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.12 F^{(2)}_0(\chi, \Theta, \phi) &
                                    = \frac{1}{4}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)(3 \sin^2 \...
```

After an error tex only recovers enough to try to check later parts of the document, the typeset output is usually not intended to be usable at all.

hence you shoudl ask about the errors, not about the pdf result.

You can not have a blank line in `equation` and the `&` syntax for alignments is for `align` not `equation` so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}



\begin{align}
F^{(2)}_0(\chi, \Theta, \phi) &= \frac{1}{4}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)(3 \sin^2 \Theta \cos 2\chi-[3 \cos^2 \Theta -1])\\
\begin{split}F^{(2)}_{1+}(\chi, \Theta, \phi) &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)c_2(j_i)(2 \sin \Theta \cos \phi \sin 2 \chi 
+\\
&\qquad 2 \sin \Theta \cos \Theta \sin \phi \cos 2 \chi  - \sin 2 \Theta \cos \phi)
\end{split}\\ 
\begin{split}F^{(2)}_{2+}(\chi, \Theta, \phi) &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)c_2(j_i)([1 + \cos^2 \Theta] \cos 2\phi \cos 2\chi -
\\
&\qquad  2 \cos \Theta \sin 2\phi \sin 2\chi {-}\sin^2\Theta \cos 2 \phi)
\end{split}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a single `align` environment, 4 explicit `\\` (line-break) directives, and two `\notag` directives. If you're pressed for (vertical) space, I suggest you replace the three `\frac` directives with `\tfrac`. Observe that there can be no blank lines inside an `align` evironment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
F^{(2)}_0(\chi, \Theta, \phi) 
  &= \tfrac{1}{4}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)\bigl(3 \sin^2\Theta \cos 2\chi
     -[3 \cos^2\Theta -1]\bigr)\\
F^{(2)}_{1+}(\chi, \Theta, \phi) 
  &= \tfrac{1}{4}\sqrt{3}h^{(2)}(j_i,j_f)c_2(j_i)\bigl(
     2\sin \Theta \cos \phi \sin 2\chi \notag\\
  &\qquad+ 2\sin \Theta \cos \Theta \sin \phi \cos 2\chi 
     - \sin 2\Theta \cos \phi\bigr)\\
F^{(2)}_{2+}(\chi, \Theta, \phi) &= \tfrac{1}{4}\sqrt{3}h^{(2)}
    (j_i,j_f)c_2(j_i)\bigl([1 + \cos^2\Theta] \cos 2\phi \cos 2\chi \notag\\
  &\qquad- 2\cos \Theta \sin 2\phi \sin 2\chi -\sin^2\Theta \cos 2\phi\bigr)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```